# How to test whether doInBackground method of AsyncTask is executing sequentially

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I've a requirement where I have to test whether `doInBackground()` of `AsyncTask` is executing sequentially or not.

> > ```
> > if (CONDITION) {
> >     new XyzAsyncTask().execute();
> > }
> >
> > private class XyzAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
> >
> >     @Override
> >     protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { }
> >
> > }
> > ```

My doubt is how to test(unit test or just print statement) that even if more than 2 times CONDITION is true, `doInBackground()` should execute sequentially

Edit:
The Problem is, In my case even when doInBackground has not finished its task, onPost is executing. How can we avoid onPost, before doInBackground executed completely.

Comment: This depends of how many times you call `new XyzAsyncTask().execute();`. If this isn't in a for or while loop (or any loop of any kind), then it should execute only one time. You can add some `Log` in the `doInBackground` to see how many times the process passed through there.

Comment: if you want to check whether your condition is true more than 2 times , you should debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Log.d("ASSERT", "Add your own message to yourself here");
```

Place this where you want to learn about the operation of the program as it occurs. This will print your message to LogCat with the tag "ASSERT" attached to it. If you want to see data or variable values, simply convert them to strings and concatenate to form a helpful log message for yourself.